# Not able to Clip Region

Tags: canvas, kineticjs

I am using following code to set clip region for my stage:

```
stage.setClip({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 500,
    height: 500
});
```

but when i am doing:

```
stage.toDataURL({
    mimeType: 'image/png',
    callback: function(dataURL){
    window.open(dataURL);
    },
    quality: 1
});
```

i am getting whole stage's picture instead of the clipping region? Is there any way that i can get image of only clip region?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing kinectjs specifically (so perhaps a little bit on a limp), it would eventually have to use the system's `toDataURL`.

`toDataURL` will return the full canvas/stage's total pixel buffer encoded as PNG, JPEG etc, there is no cropping functionality for that.

You will have to perform a cropping operation manually by creating a new stage/canvas of the size you want and then copy the portion from the original canvas onto this new canvas (normally this is simply a `drawImage` with the source canvas using a crop/clip region to the new canvas).

If kinectjs has built-in methods to do all this for you - I don't know, but this is required to do in either case when you want to extract a portion as image.